# jQuery Selectors

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I'm  finding it difficult to find examples of using jQuery, so my bad for asking such a simple question. I've got this ul:

```
<ul id="navLinks">
    <li class="selected" id="homeNavLink"></li>
    <li id="aboutNavLink"></li>
    <li id="contactNavLink"></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

I'd like to write a function to change which li has the "selected" class. Here's my attempt:

```
function changeNavLink(selectedId) {
    $("#navLinks li").each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass("selected");
    });
    $("#" + selectedId).addClass("selected");
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't have to do `.each` - functions like [`removeClass`](http://docs.jquery.com/Removeclass) can work on a set of elements just fine.

```
function changeNavLink(selectedId) {
    $("#navLinks li").removeClass('selected')
                     .filter('#' + selectedId)
                     .addClass('selected');
}
```

Should work. What it is doing is selecting all the `li` elements, removing the class `selected` from all of them, [filtering them out](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/filter#expr) to just the one with the ID passed, and adding the class `selected` to that one.

[Here is a working link](http://jsbin.com/ekanu) showing the code above at work.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#navlinks li.selected')
```

will give you the li with the "selected" class

Answer (score 1):

For the specific HTML example given, I would prefer:

```
function changeNavLink(selectedId) {
    $('#' + selectedId).addClass('selected')
                       .siblings('li')
                       .removeClass('selected');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont work with jQuery(this) ? It easier, then call function with params.
HTML:

```
<ul id="navLinks">
    <li class="selected" id="homeNavLink"></li>
    <li id="aboutNavLink"></li>
    <li id="contactNavLink"></li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(funciton(){
  $('#navLinkgs').on('click', 'li', function(){
    $this = $(this);
    $('#navLinkgs li.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $this.addClass('selected');
  });
});
```